# Notions of continuity for stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I would like to receive some clarification regarding the difference between *continuous in probability* and *continuous almost surely*. Using the definition of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process) (that match the one I have seen in other references), we have

**Continuous in probability**
for all $\varepsilon>0$
\begin{equation}
\lim_{s\rightarrow t} \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : |X_s(\omega) - X_t(\omega) | \geq \varepsilon\right\} \right)= 0
\end{equation}

and

**Continuous with probability 1 (almost surely)**
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega \in \Omega : \lim_{s\rightarrow t} |X_s(\omega) - X_t(\omega) | = 0 \right\} \right)= 1
\end{equation}

Now, I can see that the second condition is stronger than the first one, but to me they seem analogous, since the first should be valid for arbitrarily close $\varepsilon$. Obviously, my intuition is wrong, but I cannot understand how the difference can be significant. Could you please explain how the two definitions give raise to different processes? Thank you!

Comment: You have the limit in the wrong place in the definition of continuity in probability.

Comment: Thank you, now edited. Is this perhaps a relevant detail to establish the difference between the two notions?

Comment: Well, now continuity in probability at $t$ essentially says that $X_s \to X_t$ in probability as $s \to t$ and almost sure continuity at $t$ is the same thing for almost sure convergence. But we know that convergence in probability does not imply convergence almost surely so why not take one of the standard counterexamples to that and use it to build a process illustrating the difference?

Comment: Thank you again for the reply. Yes, working with a counter-example may certainly work to shed light on the difference. I was hoping that someone could provide a sound explanation by "elaborating" the definitions.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** We first examine a much easier variant, i.e., discrete-time process. Let $Y = (Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n} \qquad\text{and} \qquad \mathbb{P}(Y_n = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}. $$

Then it is clear that, for each $\epsilon > 0$,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}( \left| Y_n - 0 \right| > \epsilon)
\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}( Y_n \neq 0)
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}
= 0. $$

So $Y_n \to 0$ in probability. However, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(Y_n = 1) = \infty$, and so,  by the second Borel-Cantelli's lemma,

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_n = 1 \text{ infinitely often}) = 1. $$

So it follows that

$$ \mathbb{P}\Bigl(\limsup_{n\to\infty} Y_n = 1\Bigr) = 1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\mathbb{P}\Bigl(\liminf_{n\to\infty} Y_n = 0\Bigr) = 1. $$

So $Y_n$ does not converge as $n\to\infty$ with probability one.

Here, the difference between two notions is that the probability $\mathbb{P}(\left|Y_n - 0\right| > \epsilon)$ describes what happens to a 'typical observer $\omega$', and telling that the exceptional event occurs only to a vanishing fraction of observers for each large $n$. However, for a '*fixed* observer $\omega$', this exceptional event can happen infinitely often.

**2.** Now coming back to continuous-time case, we can borrow the above example as follows:

Let $Y=(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}$ be as above, and define $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ by

$$ X_t = \begin{cases}
Y_{\lceil 1/t \rceil}, & \text{if } t > 0, \\
0, & \text{if } t = 0.
\end{cases} $$

Then $X_t \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ in probability, whereas $X_t$ does not converge as $t \to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you very much, a clear answer both for the counter-example as well as the interpretation. The latter is really insightful!

Answer (score 1):

[Note: I am answering this question because I see no replies and I was also interested, like the OP, in understanding better this difference and the intuitive aspects. Take this as just an attempt and please, feel free to correct, add, make precise, as appropriate, so that I can also learn from my errors.]

The *almost sure continuity* is stating that each of the functions $X_\omega(s)$ that you have, for each one of the ω in the space of outcomes $\Omega$, is [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) (in the usual math sense). And that the possible exceptions $\omega's$ have an overall probability equal to $0$.

The *continuity in probability* does not guarantee the continuity of "almost all" (i.e., with probability $1$) the sample paths $X_\omega(s)$, as we have seen before.
On the contrary, each sample-path, for each $\epsilon>0$ you use, and no matter how close you get $s$ to $t$, is allowed to have still one index $s < s' < t$ (and, therefore, infinite of them) where it keeps violating the inequality $| X_\omega(t) - X_\omega(s) | < \epsilon$ (so that the continuity limit does not hold).
However, if we consider, at each index $s$, all the $\omega$ where the corresponding paths, on that index, are having the "violation" $| X_\omega(t) - X_\omega(s) | < \epsilon$, their probability must tend to zero, as $s$ tends to $t$.

Example (please, correct me if I got this one wrong):

```
    X(s)= Be( min(1, t-s) ) , for s < t   
    X(t) = 0 
    X(s)= U(0, s-t)         , for s > t
```

where $Be(p)$ denotes a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with success probability $p$ and $U(a,b)$ denotes a [Uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) in $(a,b)$.

From the right, this indexed family $X(s)$ has a limit of $0$, surely.

From the left, the limit does not hold, because infinite $1's$ will keep preventing the function from getting definitely close to $0$. However, the probability of getting those sporadic "violations" is tending to $0$, as $s$ tends to $t$.

[UPDATE: more details]

Thank you for the upvotes. I am encouraged to put in the answer some more details, which I previously glossed over because I was mostly concerned with focusing on the "intuitive" aspects for the OP and myself. Again, feel free to jump in and correct/make precise where I am exaggerating with "intuition" and hurting rigor.

The reason for the infinite $1's$ which keep popping out in the left limit to $t$ in my example above (Bernoulli with decreasing success probability), is essentially the fact that:

1.) for each $s$, the probability of having a "violation" $| X_\omega(s) - X_\omega(t) | < \epsilon$ is non zero

and ($1.$ alone would not suffice, because the probability might decrease, as it does in this case)

2.) as $s$ tends to $t$, the probability of having a violation decreases, but not fast enough" to quit "fuelling" the infinite appearances of the value $1$. More precisely, the limit of the sum of the violation probabilities, over all $s < t$, is exploding to infinity, instead of converging (a continuous analog of the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))).

If, for instance, instead of the $1/(t-s)$ probability, we consider its square, the overall "violation" probability from $s$ to $t$ would instead converge (a continuous analog of [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)) to a constant and there would be no probability left to "fuel" an infinite sequence of $1's$ to cause the limit inequality violations.

And this is, essentially, at least as I see it, the intuition with the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_di_Borel-Cantelli) (which originally addressed the discrete case, though).

This is also the reason why the fact that the "individual" (for each $s$) violation probability goes to $0$ is not enough to prevent the phenomenon of occurrence of "infinite violations" (which will prevent the continuity limit to happen). In other words, the reason why convergence in probability does not cause convergence almost sure.

What you will need to make the convergence in probability imply the convergence almost sure, is that the integral, over all $s < t$, of the violation density (the overall probability to get a violation on $(s,t)$) to be finite, in order to stop "fuelling" the infinite appearance of those violations and thus allow the continuity limit to take place.

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you! Thus, you are identifying the notion of _almost surely continuous_ with _having continuous sample path almost surely_ (the latter comes in definition of Brownian motion, for instance). If these two definitions match is a question that I have been asking myself. Unfortunately, I have never reached a resolutive answer to this. The wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process#Continuity_in_probability in the section **Relationships** argues that this is not always true. But I am still interested in answers from other sources.

Comment: Thank you EmFed. I am going to read what they say on wiki about the sample path, and in case to change my answer, if I am getting wrong. Thanks a lot for the head up. I also hope someone more expert jumps in to fix possible mistakes I have committed in the above explanation.

Comment: I am reading the definition of "Sample-continuous process" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample-continuous_process#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20sample%2Dcontinuous,are%20almost%20surely%20continuous%20functions. and they say  "the process X is called sample-continuous (or almost surely continuous, or simply continuous) if the map X(ω) : I → S is continuous as a function of topological spaces for P-almost all ω in Ω.". So this sounds to me just continuity of almost all the "sample paths". Is that wrong ?

Comment: Indeed, the continuous sample-path property is the one you described in your first post. However, _almost surely continuous_ property is defined as in the 2nd equation of the OP and it is not the same formulation. I have thought about whether the two concepts are equivalent, and I haven't found a resolutive answer, only an argument against it in the **relationships** part of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stochastic_process#Continuity_in_probability , saying "It is tempting to confuse continuity with probability one with sample continuity", following with a counter-example.

Comment: Dear EmFed I suspect  that comment on Wikipedia is wrong. It does not make sense to me at least as it assumes the existence of a definition of the sample-continuous process - possibly different from the one given on another page of Wikipedia - that makes use of an uncountable union of uncountable sets: I don't believe that because there is no such a thing in the sigma-algebra of the probability space), while we can just say that the limit must hold for all t, for each given path. I might be missing something: let's see if someone with greater insight enlightens us clarifying the matter.